# What is the default value of bitmap in android?

Tags: android, camera

If i am capturing an image and inserting it inside the database. this is working fine. But if no image is captured then what will be the default value of it?
I am using `Bitmap` for capturing and `byte[]` for storing it into database. Can anybody tell me that what will be the default value of bitmap??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't assign a resource to your Bitmap ( i.e if you declare it like this `Bitmap b;` or `Bitmap b=null;`) or if you try to assign an invalid resource  , the value will be `null` .

Comment: Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); Can you tell me if not data is coming in the thumbnail then thumbnail value will be what??

Comment: what is 'data' in `data.getExtras()` ?

Comment: if its a bundle, null. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29

Comment: Intent cameraIntent2 = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // request code
    cameraIntent2.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedUri1.toString());
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent2, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST_2);

Comment: No.till now i am not able to find where is the problem exactly??

Comment: "Can anybody tell me that what will be the default value of bitmap??" -  the default value is null. That looks solved %-)